# Construct tree with pre-order traversal given

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

A special type of tree is given where all leaves are marked with `L` and others are marked with `N`. Every node can have 0 or at most 2 nodes. The preorder traversal of the tree is given.

Give an algorithm to build the tree from this traversal.

Comment: Can you give a sample of input and output? In what format both are expected?

Comment: It's generally considered best to at least paraphrase your homework assignment before posting. Telling us a bit about what you've tried and where you got stuck helps a lot too. This is a place of questions and answers, not just "write my code for me."

Comment: @Jerry Seeing how vague is description, it _is_ probably paraphrased :)

Comment: I have the impression that the solution is not necessarily unique.  For example, the sequence `NNLL` could form the trees `(N (N L L))` or `(N (N L) L)`.

Comment: @Svante Maybe he means "0 or 2 nodes", wording is not clear.

Comment: @Nikita Rybak: Possible.  The poster might also be 999999999 monkeys who _almost_ produced something sensible.  We can never tell.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear, even with the poor English. Consider a binary tree where every leaf is marked with `L` and every non-leaf with `N`. Given is such a tree's preorder traversal. Reconstruct the tree.

Comment: @IVlad:  better say "construct one possible tree that could have this traversal."  However, this ambiguity does not feel right in the context of such an assignment.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the preorder traversal algorithm:

```
Preorder(T)
  if (T is not null)
    print T.label
    Preorder(T.left)
    Preorder(T.right)
```

Let's try to find an algorithm for an input of `NNLLNL`.

Obviously the label of the root is printed first. So you know the root has label `N`. Now the algorithm recurses on the left subtree. This is also `N` according to the input. Recurse on the left subtree of that, which is `L`. Now you have to backtrack, because you've reached a leaf. The next position in the input is also `L`, so the current node has a right child labeled with `L`. Backtrack once. Backtrack again, because you've added all the children of the current node (max 2 children). Now you're at the root again. You have to go right, because you already went left. According to the input, this is `N`. So the right child of the root is `N`. The left child of that will be `L`. This is your tree:

```
       N
     /   \
    N     N
   / \   /
  L   L L
```

Note that the solution is not necessarily unique, but this will get you a possible solution.

Pseudocode:

```
k = 0
input = ... get preorder traversal vector from user ...
Reconstruct(T)
  if input[k] == N
    T = new node with label N
    k = k + 1 
    Reconstruct(T.left)
    Reconstruct(T.right)
  else 
    T = new node with label L
    T.left = T.right = null
    k = k + 1
```

Call with a null node.

**Follow-up question**: given both the preorder and the inorder traversal of a binary tree containing distinct node labels, how can you uniquely reconstruct the tree?

Comment: Someone asked a question regarding your pseudocode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890617/need-help-deciphering-pseudocode/5890687 .

Answer (score 0):

Here is my golang version which was used to solve many problems about tree in leetcode.

```
// NewPreorderTree returns preorder tree relate to nums, nums must has not Ambiguity.
// -1 in nums represents child is null.
//
// Example 1:
//  Input: [1, 2, 3]
//  Generate:
//          1
//         /
//        2
//       /
//      3
//
// Example 2:
//  Input: [1, 2, -1, -1, 3] or [1, 2, -1, -1, 3, -1, -1]
//  Generate:
//         1
//        / \
//       2   3
func NewPreorderTree(nums ...int) *TreeNode {
    return (&preorderTree{nums}).constructTree()
}

type preorderTree struct {
    nums []int
}

func (p *preorderTree) constructTree() *TreeNode {
    if len(p.nums) == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    if p.nums[0] == -1 {
        p.nums = p.nums[1:]
        return nil
    }

    root := &TreeNode{Val: p.nums[0]}
    p.nums = p.nums[1:]
    root.Left = p.constructTree()
    root.Right = p.constructTree()
    return root
}
```